# Why Android sqlite database query filter by date is not working?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, datetime, filter

I am trying to fetch data from Android Sqlite database using its sqlite query string. Here is my code,

```
Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

        Cursor c = dbRead.query(TABLE_NAME,
                new String[]{KEY_DATA}, KEY_DUE_DATE + ">=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(today)},
                null, null, null, null);
```

In this query I am looking to get all columns which has due date greater than today.

The due date is stored in database in `'05/31/2017 12:00 AM'` format. Can anyone tell me what is wrong in my query? I am getting `0` objects from database.

Comment: Your date is not a format that Sqlite likes.. The year should be first https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: "The due date is stored in database in '05/31/2017 12:00 AM' format" -- that will make things difficult. Your format has '06/01/1904 12:00AM' as being "newer" than '05/31/2017 12:00 AM'. SQLite does not have a native date/time type. I assume that your column is of type `TEXT`, given your stated format, and so comparisons are alphabetical, not chronological. Either switch how you store the dates (`INTEGER` milliseconds since the Unix epoch, `TEXT` using ISO-8601, etc.) or pay a conversion price, on every query, using date-time functions to convert your types.

Comment: Also, you should convert `String.valueOf(today)` to a proper format that your database holds instead of relying on Java to convert correctly

Comment: Thanks guys, i changed my database format from `DATE` to `INTEGER`